# Is autocomplete search feature available in tkinter combo box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter combo box in which 1000s of values are there. Is it possible to have a autocomplete search feature in it?

Like if I type something in the combobox, it should perform some wildcard search and bring up the results.

```
            element_names = list(**a very big list**)
            dim_combo = ttk.Combobox(self, state='readonly')
            dim_combo['values'] = self.element_names
            dim_combo.place(x=100, y=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AutocompleteCombobox` method from `tkentrycomplete` module. The below example can help you out.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import tkentrycomplete

root = tk.Tk()
box_value = tk.StringVar()

def fun():
    print(box_value.get())
combo = tkentrycomplete.AutocompleteCombobox(textvariable=box_value)
test_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'grapes']
combo.set_completion_list(test_list)
combo.place(x=140, y=50)
button = tk.Button(text='but', command=fun)
button.place(x=140,y=70)

root.mainloop()
```

You can find the module here [link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-January/003041.html)

Comment: Can you pass a command with this? Also is there documentation on the AutocompleteCombobox method somewhere?

Comment: I can't find tkentrycomplete. Which Python version is this?

Comment: Great. Just the thing I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @ThanasisMattas you can create the module and import it in your code. You can paste the code of the module given in the link to your local module.

Answer (score 4):

here is good solution :)

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

lst = ['C', 'C++', 'Java',
       'Python', 'Perl',
       'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS']


def check_input(event):
    value = event.widget.get()

    if value == '':
        combo_box['values'] = lst
    else:
        data = []
        for item in lst:
            if value.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)

        combo_box['values'] = data


root = Tk()

# creating Combobox
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(root)
combo_box['values'] = lst
combo_box.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_input)
combo_box.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This solution leads to the following behavior: In the beginning, the Combobox drop down shows all options // You type one or multiple letters // If you pull open the drop down now, only the options that contain the typed letter(s) are shown in the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as this

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()


def search():
    value_to_search = var.get()
    if value_to_search == "" or value_to_search == " ":
        dim_combo['values'] = element_names
    else:
        value_to_siplay = []
        for value in element_names:
            if value_to_search in value:
                value_to_siplay.append(value)
        dim_combo['values'] = value_to_siplay


element_names = list([str(a) for _ in range(100) for a in range(10)])

dim_combo = ttk.Combobox(root, state='readonly')
dim_combo['values'] = element_names
dim_combo.pack()

var=StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()

search_button = Button(root, text="search", command=search)
search_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The function "search" search inside the `element_names` of the Combobox for the elements that contains the string that you want to search, so if in the box we have `["hello", "mahe", "pola"]` and you search `he` the checkbox will display only `["hello", "mahe"]`

Comment: Let me check and get back to you on this, thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the tk.OptionMenu() widget to implement the ComboBox dropdown in my code.

With this widget, I found that if I also include an tk.Entry() widget right next to it, with both widgets sharing the same textVariable, tkinter automatically works as an autosearch in the dropdown.

Here is a short snippet

```
selectedItemText = tk.StringVar()

aEntry = tk.Entry(self.master, kw_tkEntry)
aEntry['textvariable'] = selectedItemText

aComboBox = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, selectedItemText, *set(largeDataList))
```

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Can you please share the entire code. This answer doesn't give an overall picture to me as to how to use it. Thanks