# Show the possibilities while typing in entry field tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When the user starts typing into the entry field, I want the possibilities shown underneath the tkinter entry field just as if you would type into the Google search bar. The possibilities are placed in the fruits array.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Pear"]

label = tk.Label(text="Fruit")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry = tk.Entry()
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

You can find an image of what I want here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnozv.png (I am not allowed to post images yet)

How can I make this entry field  act the same as the Google search bar?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-January/003041.html) can help

Answer (score 3):

```
# Import the Required libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Create an instance of tkinter frame or window
win= Tk()

# Update the Entry widget with the selected item in list
def check(e):
   v= entry.get()
      if v=='':
      data= values
   else:
      data=[]
      for item in values:
         if v.lower() in item.lower():
            data.append(item)
   update(data)

def update(data):
   # Clear the Combobox
   menu.delete(0, END)
   # Add values to the combobox
   for value in data:
      menu.insert(END,value)


# Add a Label widget
label= Label(win, text= "Demo Combobox Widget", font= ('Helvetica 15
bold'), background= "green3")
label.pack(padx= 10, pady= 25)

# Add a Bottom Label
text= Label(win, text="Select your prefered fruit")
text.pack(padx= 15,pady= 20)

# Create an Entry widget
entry= Entry(win, width= 35)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',check)

# Create a Listbox widget to display the list of items
menu= Listbox(win)
menu.pack()

# Create a list of all the menu items
values= ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Pear"]
# Add values to our combobox
update(values)

# Binding the combobox onclick

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help out. This is not exactly what I meant.
For this example I only used 4 values but I will use a list of 60+ values. I do not want the list visible before the user starts typing. Also when the correct value is visible I would like the user to be able to click it or to use the arrow key to select and use the value. Just like the Google search bar.

Comment: Maybe this is something you are looking for :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649709/is-autocomplete-search-feature-available-in-tkinter-combo-box

Answer (score 0):

> When the user starts typing into the entry field, I want the
> possibilities shown underneath the tkinter entry field just as if you
> would type into the Google search bar.

> How can I make this entry field act the same as the Google search bar.

The solution can be fixed.

- Add `Entry` widget.
- Add `Listbox` widget.
- Create `check_key()` function. This will search in `Listbox` for what you type.
- Add `e.bind` for `check_key()` function. We'll be using Walrus.
- Create `update()` function. It will remove item when pressing the
  spacebar to update the Listbox.
- Create `items_selected()` function. If you desire, then click the
  item  on Listbox to update the Entry widget.
- Add `lb.bind` for `items_selected()` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Search Engines')

#fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Pear"]

lst = ['san francisco weather', 'san francisco', 'san francisco giants',
        'san francisco valleyr', 'san francisco state university',
        'san francisco hotels', 'san francisco 49ers', 'san fernando',
        'san francisco mission', 'san francisco zip code']

def check_key(event: bool) -> bool:
   if (value := event.widget.get()) =='':
       data = lst
   else:
       data = [item for item in lst if value.lower() in item.lower()]
                                    
   update(data)

def update(data: str) -> None:  
    lb.delete(0, 'end')

    for item in data:
        lb.insert('end', item)

def items_selected(event: None) -> None:
    selected_langs = ",".join([lb.get(i) for i in lb.curselection()])
    e.delete(0, tk.END)
    e.insert(0, selected_langs)      

e = tk.Entry(root)
 
lb = tk.Listbox(root)

e.pack()
lb.pack()

e.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_key)
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', items_selected)

update(lst)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]